# "illegal subclass ABRemotePersonView instantiating; client should use only NSRemoteView" on attempt to instantiate CNContactViewController

Tags: swift, macos, macos-high-sierra, cncontactviewcontroller

I'm trying to show CNContactViewController for a selected contact in a table, which is shown in a modal window:

```
        let controller = CNContactViewController.init()
        controller.contact = contact.contact
        guard let selectedCellView = contactsTable.view(atColumn: 0, row: contactsTable.selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: false) else {
            print("ERROR: selected cell is not visible")
            return
        }
        let bounds = selectedCellView.bounds
        presentViewController(controller, asPopoverRelativeTo: bounds, of: selectedCellView, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .transient)
```

The popover comes ok, everything is ok, except of console output:

```
2017-11-23 14:45:47.322456+0100 Link-em[9253:1949091] warning: illegal subclass ABRemotePersonView instantiating; client should use only NSRemoteView (
    0   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff68c881c0 -[NSRemoteView _preSuperInit] + 195
    1   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff68c88544 -[NSRemoteView initWithFrame:] + 25
    2   AddressBook                         0x00007fff41e33a4e -[ABRemotePersonView initWithFrame:] + 77
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff41f341c5 -[NSView init] + 62
    4   ContactsUI                          0x00007fff442fa83b -[CNContactViewController loadView] + 50
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff41f899d2 -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff41f8993d -[NSViewController view] + 30
    7   ContactsUI                          0x00007fff442fa8c2 -[CNContactViewController _remotePersonView] + 53
    8   ContactsUI                          0x00007fff442fa9a5 -[CNContactViewController serviceViewControllerProxy] + 32
    9   ContactsUI                          0x00007fff442fa732 -[CNContactViewController apiAdapter] + 73
    10  ContactsUI                          0x00007fff442faad1 -[CNContactViewController setContact:] + 71
    11  Link-em                             0x000000010000702f _T07Link_em15ContactsServiceC5getUISo23CNContactViewControllerCSgSS3for_tF + 239
    12  Link-em                             0x0000000100012f37 _T07Link_em27ContactsTableViewControllerC11doubleClickyypF + 1367
    13  Link-em                             0x0000000100013588 _T07Link_em27ContactsTableViewControllerC11doubleClickyypFTo + 72
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff426dea7a -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 312
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff42185777 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff421f9188 -[NSTableView _sendAction:to:row:column:] + 121
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff421f75c7 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 7186
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff4287da01 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5891
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff4287a658 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2359
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff42879904 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 497
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff426da937 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 307
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff4217a0f6 -[NSApplication _doModalLoop:peek:] + 551
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff4235ed63 __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke_2 + 64
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff4235ed10 __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke + 75
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff4280c101 _NSTryRunModal + 100
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff42177b3d -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 133
    27  Link-em                             0x0000000100010775 
    [...skipped rest...]
)
```

Is there anything I can do about it? Looks like a bug in MacOS, but may be I didn't initialize something properly?
Or may be such controllers could not be instantiated from modal window?

Comment: Did you find a way around this?

Comment: @strangetimes, unfortunately no, however I've not noticed any side effect of this error, so for now I'm just ignoring it

Comment: The CNContactViewController is broken since it's release. The best way currently is to make your own implementation based on Contacts framework and stay away from this generic view controller (lots of work but saves you from bad reviews and crashes)

Comment: @MarekH, did you meet any crashes or bad reviews on practice? I've not noticed anything bad, except of the messages in the console. Though I didn't try to get through the review yet. Or may be you mean bad reviews from the users, who'll read logs locally? IMHO too much work to justify erroneous output.

Comment: Yes, cause I needed to allow users to change data inside. As you see it is still bridged to abpersonview. They broke KVO cause I always got a new object CNContact/ABPerson. So the one I was displaying didn't match the one after edit. Users thought it is my app that is faulty.

Comment: Update 2020. The new error is:  warning: deprecated subclass NSLayerCentricRemoteView instantiating; client should use only NSRemoteView ...

Comment: I gave it high hopes in 2020 but it's been 2 years and it's still broken